# Setting custom response header in plain Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

My situation of using Node.js is like this:

```
Client --> Node.js --> External Rest API
```

So, vice-versa will be the response. As per requirement, I need to capture response headers from `External Rest API` and append it to `Node.js`'s response header and to a client I need to send it as a single response header. To which I tried like this (this header is from Node.js side):

```
var resHeaders = {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,Last-modified,Connection,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Date',
                     'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Type,Last-modified,Connection,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Date'
                 };
```

I am getting `External API`'s response header in a variable like this:

```
var curlHeadersResp; //I am executing curl to get response headers
```

Finally I am trying to combile both like this:

```
var finalRespHeaders = new Array();
finalRespHeaders.push(curlHeadersResp);
finalRespHeaders.push(JSON.stringify(resHeaders));

res.writeHead(200, JSON.stringify(finalRespHeaders));
```

But the response header I am getting is in junk like this:

> HTTP/1.1 200 ["HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\nDate: Mon, 03 Feb 2014 09:25:06 GMT\r\n\r\n","{\"Content-Type\":\"application/json\",\"Access-Control-Allow-Origin\":\"*\",\"Access-Control-Allow-Methods\":\"GET,PUT,POST,DELETE\",\"Access-Control-Allow-Headers\":\"Content-Type,Last-modified,Connection,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Date\",\"Access-Control-Expose-Headers\":\"Content-Type,Last-modified,Connection,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Date\"}"]
>   Date: Mon, 03 Feb 2014 09:25:38 GMT

I think it is a problem of concatination. My question is if anyone has any idea of generating dynamic headers or anyone could shed some light on this it would be very helpful.

**Why I am doing like this?** Because of cross-domain requests problems, so I don't have control on external server. So from my Node.js side I need to append Allow cross domain headers so that cross domain requests are possible.

Comment: According to [Node.js http Docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_reasonphrase_headers), you should pass headers as an object, while you're passing a JSON string.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny, yes I tried that, but just I am getting as `[object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

From Node.JS Documentation:

```
//response.writeHead(statusCode, [reasonPhrase], [headers])
//                    number      string          object

var body = 'hello world';
response.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Length': body.length,
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
```

You don't need to create an array an push the objects to it, join together the `curlHeadersResp` and `resHeaders`:

```
Object.keys(curlHeadersResp).forEach(function (element) {
    resHeaders[element] = curlHeadersResp[element;
});
```

Where you write the header you don't need to stringify the object, just:

```
res.writeHead(200, resHeaders);
```

Comment: Yes I tried that, but just I am getting as `[object Object]`

Comment: Updated answer, check it out, you need to have in the end an Object! NOT a string or an array

Comment: Ok, thanks I tried this, but now I am getting cannot call keys on non-object error. I think it's because `curlHeadersResp`I am getting in json string.

Comment: Yes, this may be the problem, parse it and try again

Comment: Yes I tried, now I am getting these type of error, unexpected token H date=Mon   Feb 03 2014 10:07:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)